Vertex paint not painting on any objects
I'm sure I'm doing something silly but vertex paint is just not applying.
I'm watching this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpzapi4vkxw&t=741s where he vertex paints the eye at 12:00
The eyeball can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Se0Nl0E7ya7xm0wXaqy3aWeNR4jTCzOo/view?usp=drive_link
Thank you in advance!

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

OK my apologies I will try on 4.2 and check back
